# Matlab error matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to write a code in matlab that would solve quadratics, but I get an error in the first bit of my code on line 41.
The last bit of the code just calculate the values of x and inform the user if the values are with complex roots or normal numbers

```
function quadraticsolver1
    clc
    clear all

    fprintf ('Welcome to Quadratic Solver\n')
    fprintf ('Created by Rémi Tuyaerts 2013\n')

    % Get value for a
    a=input('enter value for a ', 's');
    % if value of a is empty or not numeric ask user to reenter it
    while isempty(a); ischar(a);
        disp ('The value entered for a is incorrect')
        a=input('Please reenter value for a ', 's');
    end

    % Get value for b
    b=input('enter value for b ', 's');
    % if value of b is empty or not numeric ask user to reenter it
    while isempty(b); ischar (b);
        disp ('The value entered for b is incorrect')
        b=input('Please reenter value for b', 's');
    end

    % Get value for c
    c=input('enter value for c ', 's');
    % if value of c is empty or not numeric ask user to reenter it
    while isempty (c); ischar (c);
        disp ('The value entered for a is incorrect')
        c=input('Please reenter value for c ', 's');

    end

    % calculating the value of the sqrt
    g = (b.^2)-(4*a.*c);
end
```

Comment: This is quite difficult to read, please indent everything properly.  Also, which line is line 41 in the file?

Comment: Which one is line 41? You posted less then 41 lines of code!

Comment: You don't need a clear all in the first line of a function.

Comment: the last line, the one that defines g = (b.^2)-(4*a.*c);

Comment: also did you mean to use `&&` or `||` in the `while` tests (instead of semicolons)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's possible to tell without examples of input that you used, but I think the problem is this:

```
c=input('Please reenter value for c ', 's');
```

The `'s'` means that the input is treated as a string of characters, not a number.  You then try to use it as a number at the end of the function, which is clearly wrong.  Sometimes this will actually give an answer, but I suspect that you entered numbers with different numbers of digits.  This would mean that, as strings, their sizes would be different and you get an error.

The solution is to remove the `'s'` arguments from all the `input` functions because you don't need them.

**EDIT:** If for some reason you do want them as strings initially, you can convert the strings back to numbers like this:

```
a = str2num(a);
```

Comment: yea the 's' is ther eon purpose so i can show an error message if the user inputs a value that is not a number. I force matlab to take the input value as a character and then it check if its a number or a other character. If it is a character an error message comes up other wise it continues.

Comment: here is the bit of code that does that

Comment: % Get value for a 
a=input('enter value for a ', 's');

% if value of a is empty or not numeric ask user to reenter it
while isempty(a); ischar(a);
disp ('The value entered for a is incorrect')
a=input('Please reenter value for a ');
end</code>

Comment: OK, but then why are you using the strings in the equation on the last line?  I'll update the answer...

Comment: Also, `input` *already* gives an error message if you don't give it a number, why implement your own?

Comment: yea i know it gives you an error message but i wanted to have my own one

Comment: OK, well hopefully my edit to the answer will explain how to fix the problem